# Add strings to a file with commands

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to add:

```
user_xattr,acl,barrier=1
```

to my /etc/fstab file. Is there a way to do this via the via shell script?

I only want to edit the '`/`' mount.

Here is what I have before I manually edit it:

```
UUID=eb287d10-60a8-4a9a-9148-5f907fc7a8be / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Here is what it looks like after I manually add the lines:

```
UUID=eb287d10-60a8-4a9a-9148-5f907fc7a8be / ext4 user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

I know that the `sed -i` command will not work here because it only adds lines...

Also script be run on multiple computers so it has to be able to "know" that the UUID will be different.

Comment: You can use sed to replace, also would passing the UUID as a parameter to a command work ?

Comment: If I am getting this right then you mean pasting in the UUID of the drive for the command? If so then this script is supposed to be automated. Here is a link:https://github.com/elliot-labs/Samba4-AD-DC-Auto-Setup

Comment: if you're managing a lab or cluster, check out ansible (http://ansible.com), to automate this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not really yet and I don't have any budget this is more of a charity thing with support for future projects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, `sed` could work perfectly well, but here are some more choices as well:

#### 1. sed

```
sudo sed -i.old -r '/[ \t]\/[ \t]/{s/(ext4[\t ]*)([^\t ]*)/\1\2,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1/}' /etc/fstab
```

#### Explanation:

- `-i.old` : Edit the file in place and create `fstab.old` as a backup of the original file before the changes.
- `-r` : Enable extended regular expressions.
- `/[ \t]\/[ \t]/{}` : If this line matches a `/` surrounded by a space or tab (if this line describes the `/` mountpoint).
- `s/(ext4[\t ]*)([^\t ]*)/\1\2,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1/` : `s/pat/replacement/` is the substitution operator, it will replace `pat` with `replacement`. Here, we are matching `ext4` and any following space or tab (needed to anchor the match, if your file systems are not ext4, you'll need to change that) and then capturing (that's what the parentheses do) the longest stretch of non-whitespace characters after that. In other words, capturing the options field of fstab. We then replace those with `\1` (the first captured pattern), `\2` (the 3nd capturef pattern, the original options) plus the extra options you wanted to add.

#### 2. Perl

```
sudo perl -i.old -pane 's/$F[3]/$F[3],user_xattr,acl,barrier=1/ if $F[1] eq "/"' /etc/fstab
```

#### Explanation:

- `-i.old` :  Again, this will cause the file to be edited in place and a backup called `fstab.old` will be created.
- `-pane` : `-p` means print each line, `-a` automatically splits input lines into fields on white space and saves them as the array `@F`. `-n` means read line by line and `-e` lets you pass a script on the command line.
- The actual script will add the extra options to the current value of the 4th field (`$F[3]`,1st field is `$F[0]`) only if the second ffield (`$F[1]`, the mount point) is `/`.

#### 3. awk

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.old && 
 awk '($2=="/"){$4=$4",user_xattr,acl,barrier=1"}1;' /etc/fstab.old | sudo tee /etc/fstab
```

#### Explanation:

Most versions of `awk` don't allow in place editing so the first command will create a backup copy. The `awk` will then check if the 2nd field is `/` and if so, will add the required text to the 4th field, the options. The `1;` is awk shorthand for "print the line". The `sudo tee` is just a trick to allow printing to `/etc/fstab` since simple redirection won't work with `sudo`.

#### 4. pure bash

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc.fstab.old
while read fs mp ty op du pa; do 
    [[ $mp = "/" ]] && op="user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,""$op"; 
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" "$fs" "$mp" "$ty" "$op" "$du" "$pa"; 
done < /etc/fstab.old | sudo tee /etc/fstab
```

#### Explanation

- `while read fs mp ty op du pa; do ...; done < /etc/fstab` : Read each fstab line and split into the relevant fields.
- `[[ $mp = "/" ]] && op="user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,""$op";` if the mount point is `/`, add the extra options to `$op`.
- The `printf` just prints each line correctly.

Comment: I want the UUID to be ignored because it will be different from computer to computer. Also thanks for this I will have to test it.
NOTE: I am only using shell scripts and am not interested in using pearl or any other programming languages. (I am not sure if awk is one)

Comment: Also good Idea in making a backup file. I assume that I can change '.bak' to '.original' if I want...

Comment: @ElliotLabs all of these run in the shell, yes `awk` and `perl` are languages but here they are being run as shell commands, botho will be available on any *nix machine (there are some older, minimalist AIX that might not have one or the other but those are rare). Anyway, I added a pure bash option as well. And yes, I know you want the UUID to be ignored, that's why all my methods use a different approach to find the relevant line.

Comment: I just want it to be as compatible as possible because a minimal install might not have some of  these commands. I understand that it is unlikely but I am doing this just for good measure...

Comment: @ElliotLabs _all_ Linux installs will have both `perl` and `awk`. As I said, you _might_ find a minimal AIX that lacks one or both but never a Linux. Also note, that any system that lacks perl or awk is equally likely to lack `sed`.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side :) LOVE you answer it is the best one that I have received!

Comment: @ElliotLabs glad you like it :). Just be aware that both `perl` and `awk` are very much on the safe side. `sed` is also an external program and not part of the shell. In fact, the least portable of all of these is the pure bash one since minimal systems will probably not have `bash` installed. They _will_ have `awk` for example though.

Comment: !!! I did not realize. OK I think I will use the `awk` one in my final script. I have gotta test it...

Comment: The sed command just did not wok it messed up my fstab file and caused my computer not to start properly... Can you check your syntax to make sure that it works? It splits the errors=remount-ro line in half so it looks like this errorstuff inserteds=remount-ro. Can you check your syntax? thanks!

Comment: @ElliotLabs sorry, my bad. There was indeed a bug (I was using `\s` which works strangely), it should work OK now.

Comment: It appears to be working again. Thanks for the edit on the sed command!

Answer (score 1):

`sed -i` is not used **only** to add lines as you said. It can be used in many other cases. And in your case like follow:

```bsh
str="/[[:space:]]*ext4[[:space:]]*errors=remount-ro[[:space:]]*0[[:space:]]*1"
sed -i.bak "s#$str#/ ext4 user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,errors=remount-ro 0 1#" /etc/fstab
```

Like this `$str` which is equal with something like `/ ext4 errors=remount-r 0 1` (where each space can be any group of white spaces `<tab>` and `<space>`) will be replaced with `/ ext4 user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,errors=remount-ro 0 1` in  `/etc/fstab` file.

The class `[:space:]` (which match the whitespace characters `<tab>` and `<space>`) is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), so you should have no problems in using it in any shell.

Comment: +1. You can use `&` in place of `$str` on the right-hand side.

Comment: This won't work, the OP specified that the UUIDs will be different since this needs to be run on multiple machines. Also, this will fail if the `fstab` fields are separated by tabs or even multiple spaces.